# How to grant nifi access to write to directory

Tags: apache-nifi, cloudera

Am trying to use NiFi's `putFile` processor, but it keeps thrwoing `AccessDeninedException` how can I grant Nifi access to the targeted directory ?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a NiFi issue but rather a story about setting up the environment / infrastructure in which NiFi runs.  Would setting appropriate file system permissions as part of the setup of the environment not solve the issue?

Comment: am using it in cloudera CDH, is there a specific user to grant access for ?

Comment: the same user that run nifi ? Nifi